# Produce a series of numbered columns in a data frame which contain a function of the previous variable

Tags: r

A complete beginner to R, moving from SAS and very much struggling with some basic techniques including knowing where to look for answers.  I hope you can help me out here.

My overall objective is to try and predict the survival of a population over time where there is a an individual specific but time invariant probability of failing at each time point.  At the moment I have successfully created a dataframe consisting of say 5 rows and two variables p and S0 which indicate the probability of failure at each time point and the survival at time 0 which is set to 1 for all rows.  As shown below

[image]

What I wish to do in an efficient manner is expand the data frame to 5 periods working out the individual probability of survival by applying the following formula S(i) = S(i-1) - p*S(i-1), such that I end up with the following data frame with meaningfully named columns/variables ...

[image]

I'm so tempted to try and do this via a loop, but I suspect that would be a very inefficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, a loop will do fine.**  Here is an example crafted for more general use:

```
X <- data.frame(P = c(0.01, 0.3, 0.02, 0.015, 0.2), S0 = 1)

update <- function(x, p) x * (1-p)
fname <- "S0"
basename <- "S"

for (i in 1:5) {
  newname <- paste0(basename, i)
  X[[newname]] <- update(X[[fname]], X$P)
  fname <- newname
}
```

**To check efficiency**, I timed this loop for a data frame with 100,000,000 records created randomly *via*

```
X <- data.frame(P = rbeta(1e8, 2, 2), S0 = 1)
```

It took 1.58 seconds of user time and 1.78 seconds of elapsed time.  Unless you have a much larger data frame or need to generate many more columns, this looks efficient enough.